# SQL Server not inserting geometry type (worked in Postgres though)

Tags: sql-server, shapefile, geokettle

**Problem**: insert a shapefile (.shp) into sql server

**Steps**:

**1-** I use Geokettle to transform .shp to sql server query

**2-** I use the sql query to create the table in sql server

the SQL Server code looks like:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CARGA_SHAPE](the_geom, STATEFP, COUNTYFP, 
COUNTYNS, AFFGEOID, 
GEOID, NAME, LSAD, ALAND, AWATER) 
VALUES (MULTIPOLYGON ((
(-83.35353099999999 39.197585, 
 -82.78589099999999 39.168769, 
 -82.80709 38.948073, 
 -83.04361999999999 38.956939, 
 -83.212107 38.960148, 
 -83.270817 39.015791, 
 -83.314589 39.052195, 
 -83.385637 39.055197, 
 -83.35353099999999 39.197585)
  )),
 '39','131',
 '01074078','0500000US39131',
 '39131','Pike',
 '06',1140324458,
  9567612);

INSERT INTO dbo.CARGA_SHAPE(the_geom, STATEFP, COUNTYFP, COUNTYNS, AFFGEOID, 
GEOID, NAME, LSAD, ALAND, AWATER) 
VALUES (MULTIPOLYGON (((
-98.807771 43.935223, -98.331508 
 43.937708, -98.331544 
 43.868189, -98.32524199999999 
 43.851057999999995, -98.320595 
 43.498650999999995, -98.705782 43.499319, 
-98.79458799999999 43.499187, 
-98.796965 43.848575, -98.807771 
 43.935223))),
'46','003',
'01266983','0500000US46003',
'46003','Aurora',
'06',1834813753,11201379);
```

but I get the error message:

```
Message 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '39.197585'-
Message 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '43.935223'-
Message 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '44.855951'-
```

However, when I go through the same steps using Geokettle to get Postgres query, it works correctly.

I do not know why sql server is not accepting since I am using its 2012 version (with spatial tools).

the Postgres code looks like:

```
INSERT INTO mapa(the_geom, STATEFP, COUNTYFP, COUNTYNS, 
AFFGEOID, GEOID, "name", LSAD, ALAND, AWATER) 
VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON (((
-83.35353099999999 39.197585, 
-82.78589099999999 39.168769, 
-82.80709 38.948073, 
-83.04361999999999 38.956939, 
-83.212107 38.960148, 
-83.270817 39.015791, 
-83.314589 39.052195, 
-83.385637 39.055197, 
-83.35353099999999 39.197585)))'
,-1)
,'39','131','01074078','0500000US39131',
'39131','Pike','06',1140324458,9567612);

INSERT INTO mapa(the_geom, STATEFP, COUNTYFP, COUNTYNS, AFFGEOID, GEOID, "name", LSAD, ALAND, AWATER) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON (((-98.807771 43.935223, -98.331508 43.937708, -98.331544 43.868189, -98.32524199999999 43.851057999999995, -98.320595 43.498650999999995, -98.705782 43.499319, -98.79458799999999 43.499187, -98.796965 43.848575, -98.807771 43.935223)))',-1),'46','003','01266983','0500000US46003','46003','Aurora','06',1834813753,11201379);
```

Comment: I've formatted your SQL. I've never used `multipolygon` before but I note two things: 1. You have two `insert` SQL statements. You should isolate the issue to just one of them. (I guess the first); 2. The examples of `multipolygon` that I see have pairs of coordinates. You appear to have one left over in your first insert (that happens to match the number in you error)

Comment: This one also only has pairs in it's `multipolygon`: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-sql-server-spatial-data/